# I'm always remain logged into facebook from within app

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using an `FBSDKLoginButton`. The problem is that I'm always logged in to facebook within the app. Even if I close the app, and go to the facebook app... ensure I'm logged out there... whenever I open my app and get to the log in button, it is greyed out with "Log out" written... not only that but I'm able to present an `FBSDKShareDialog` and `post` to facebook... even though the facebook app says I'm logged out.

How do terminate my app's facebook access? Right now all I can do is completely delete the app from the iphone to terminate access.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if you are already logged into Facebook you have to check if the **facebookToken** is still active or not, like this;

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]==nil)
{
  //not logged in
}
```

And to logout from Facebook when you close the application you have to call;

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logOut];
```

You can call that logout option wither at AppDelegate.h - `(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` method or manually by placing a application logout button.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks.  I am checking currentAccesstoken as you've shown but it is never nil... I will use that logout method from within the app.

Comment: @AmeetSharma currentAccesstoken becomes nill once you logged out from the app, till that it will always have a value from the previous login. So you have to logout to invalidate the AccessToken

Comment: ah... I thought logging out from the facebook app would log it out. Thanks for clarifying.